# definition of linux perf cache-misses event?

Tags: linux, profiling, cpu, performancecounter, perf

I am trying to use linux perf to profile cache performance.

perf list shows there is a cache-misses event.  However, what's the definition of this "cache-misses" event?

Is it one of L1D/L1i cache, L2 cache or L3 cache?

Thanks!

Comment: This perf event has different mappings for cpu models. What is your cpu, is it intel or amd and what is the exact cpu model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cache-misses` event corresponds to the misses in the last level cache (LLC). Note that this is an architectural performance monitoring event, that is supposed to behave consistently across microarchitectures.

This can be verified from the source code - [cache-misses](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L35)

The first 2 digits of the hexadecimal **0x412e** refer to the **umask**(41) and the last 2 digits refer to the **event-select**(2e).

From the Intel software developer's manual (look at the chapter on Performance Monitoring)

**Last Level Cache Misses— Event select 2EH, Umask 41H**

"This event counts each cache miss condition for references to the last level on-die cache. The event count may include speculation and cache line fills due to the first-level cache hardware prefetcher, but may exclude cache line fills due to other hardware-prefetchers."

Comment: When there is L3 cache shared by 4 or 8 cores (each has own L1 and L2), will LLC be L3 or L2 miss?

Comment: @osgx: The **last** level of cache is L3 in that case.

Comment: Is there a non-generic name for this event?  Like `offcore_requests.l3_miss_demand_data_rd` only counts demand-loads for data, and `mem_load_retired.l3_miss` counts instructions, not prefetches, and only loads.  I didn't notice anything else in `perf list` that might give the same counts.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Could it be `LONGEST_LAT_CACHE.MISS` ? For Skylake, this is defined as : https://github.com/intel/perfmon/blob/main/SKL/events/skylake_core.json#L893.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, thanks. The umask/event match and  `perf stat -e cache-misses,LLC-load-misses,mem_load_retired.l3_miss,LONGEST_LAT_CACHE.MISS  awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){}}'` shows identical counts for those two events.  The descriptions can't seem to make up their mind whether it includes requests generated by HW prefetch (especially from L2); the brief description in the linked source says *demand* misses, then the full says "hardware prefetches from L1 and L2", but "not all" L3 misses.  But it should at least include all demand requests, code, load, or RFO (store).