# Optimizing double->long conversion with memory operand using perf?

Tags: performance, x86, x86-64, perf

I have an x86-64 Linux program which I am attempting to optimize via `perf`. The perf report shows the hottest instructions are scalar conversions from double to long with a memory argument, for example:

```asm
cvttsd2si (%rax, %rdi, 8), %rcx
```

which corresponds to C code like:

```c
extern double *array;
long val = (long)array[idx];
```

(This is an unusual bottleneck but the code itself is very unusual.)

To inform optimizations I want to know if these instructions are hot because of the load from memory, or because of the arithmetic conversion itself. What's the best way to answer this question? What other data should I collect and how should I proceed to optimize this?

---

Some things I have looked at already. CPU counter results show 1.5% cache misses per instruction:

```
    30686845493287      cache-references
     2140314044614      cache-misses           #    6.975 % of all cache refs
          52970546      page-faults
  1244774326560850      instructions
   194784478522820      branches
     2573746947618      branch-misses          #    1.32% of all branches
          52970546      faults
```

Top-down performance monitors show we are primarily backend-bound:

```
frontend bound      retiring       bad speculation        backend bound
10.1%               25.9%          4.5%                   59.5%
```

Ad-hoc measurement with `top` shows all CPUs pegged at 100% suggesting we are not waiting on memory.

A final note of interest: when run on AWS EC2, the code is dramatically slower (44%) on AMD vs Intel with the same core count. (Tested on Ice Lake 8375C vs EPYC 7R13). What could explain this discrepancy?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: As a quick check I’d convert to 64 bit, or possibly convert (x + 2^31) to unsigned long and subtract 2^31. As long as the slightly changed semantics is ok for you.

Comment: But you can’t optimise a single instruction. Show the complete loop that you want to run fast.

Comment: @gnasher729: What are you talking about with converting to 64-bit?  This already is 64-bit code, converting a 64-bit double to 64-bit `long` (as you can see from the 64-bit `%rcx` destination).

Comment: The instruction's performance isn't dependent on operand-size anyway. (https://uops.info/ shows no difference between R32 and R64 forms.  The higher latency for the memory source form is a benchmarking bug on uops.info, due to using a 32-bit store.  I emailed Andreas about it.)

Comment: The Intel/AMD difference for this instruction is very small if there's any.  Same 1/clock throughput on both ICL and Zen3.  Similar latency as part of a loop that does an integer store to create a round trip to make a timeable loop.  (The difference in the latency upper bound on the XMM form might be Intel/AMD differences in latency of `movq xmm, rax` to get the data back into vector regs.)  So probably the performance difference is in cache misses / prefetching, or other code if you're sure this instruction wasn't missing in any level of cache.

Comment: If you could use 32-bit integers, that might let it vectorize with AVX2, depending what you do with the results.  Packed conversion to `int64_t` or `uint64_t` is available with AVX-512, which Ice Lake has, so you might get some speedup if your use case is vectorization friendly.

Comment: I was going to say the indexed addressing mode might not micro-fuse (or at least unlaminates at issue/rename).  But even Ice Lake can't micro-fuse a memory operand as part of a multi-uop instruction.  (This is 2 with a register source, 3 with memory).  So this is the ideal instruction for doing this conversion if you're not vectorizing; there's no faster way to emulate it, and no downside to the indexed addressing mode.  The AVX form has no advantage.

Comment: **Keep in mind that lots of counts for `cycles` on an instruction often means that the one before it was slow, or that one of its inputs was from the actual slow instruction.  If you just saw this one instruction hot in `perf report`, it's not the actual key to what's going on.**

Comment: You could `perf record -e mem_load_retired.l2_miss`  or something, which is a precise event and will tell you if this load is causing a lot of misses.  Or maybe `mem_trans_retired.load_latency_gt_16` or `_32` could be interesting, if it works the way I think `perf list` is explaining, checking latency from when it's first sent to an execution unit until actual completion.  Anyway, something to see if the load uop is being slow or otherwise missing in cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To inform optimizations I want to know if these instructions are hot because of the load from memory, or because of the arithmetic conversion itself. What's the best way to answer this question?

I think there is two main reason for this instruction to be slow. 1. There is a dependency chain and the latency of this instruction is a problem since the processor is waiting on it to execute other instructions. 2. There is a cache miss (saturating the memory with such instruction is improbable unless many cores are doing memory-based operations).

First of all, tracking what is going on on a specific instruction is hard (especially if the instruction is not executed a lot of time). You need to use **precise events** to track the root of the problem, that is, events for which the exact instruction addresses that caused the event are available. Only a (small) subset of all events are precise one.

Regarding (1), the latency of the instruction should be about 12 cycles on both architecture (although it might be slightly more on the AMD processor, I do not expect a 44% difference). The target processor are able to execute multiple instruction at the same time in a given cycle. Instructions are executed on different port and are also pipelined. The port usage matters to understand what is going on. This means all the instruction in the hot loop matters. You cannot isolate this specific instruction. Modern processors are insanely complex so a basic analysis can be tricky. On Ice Lake processors, you can measure the average port usage with events like `UOPS_DISPATCHED.PORT_XXX` where `XXX` can be `0`, `1`, `2_3`, `4_9`, `5`, `6`, `7_8`. Only the first three matters for this instruction. The `EXE_ACTIVITY.XXX` events may also be useful. You should check if a port is saturated and which one. AFAIK, none of these events are precise so you can only analyse a block of code (typically the hot loop). On Zen 3, the ports are `FP23` and `FP45`. IDK what are the useful events on this architecture (I am not very familiar with it).

On Ice Lake, you can check the `FRONTEND_RETIRED.LATENCY_GE_XXX` events where XXX is a power of two integer (which should be precise one so you can see if this instruction is the one impacting the events). This help you to see whether the front-end or the back-end is the limiting factor.

Regarding (2), you can check the latency of the memory accesses as well as the number of L1/L2/L3 cache hits/misses. On Ice Lake, you can use events like `MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.XXX` where `XXX` can be for example `L1_MISS` `L1_HIT`, `L2_MISS`, `L2_HIT`, `L3_MISS` and `L3_HIT`. Still on Ice Lake, t may be useful to track the latency of the memory operation with `MEM_TRANS_RETIRED.LOAD_LATENCY_GT_XXX` where `XXX` is again a power of two integer.

You can also use LLVM-MCA to simulate the scheduling of the loop instruction statically on the target architecture (do not consider branches). This is very useful to understand deeply what the scheduler can do pretty easily.

> What could explain this discrepancy?

The latency and reciprocal throughput should be about the same on the two platform or at least close. That being said, for the same core count, the two certainly do not operate at the same frequency. If this is not coming from that, then I doubt this instruction is actually the problem alone (tricky scheduling issues, wrong/inaccurate profiling results, etc.).

> CPU counter results show 1.5% cache misses per instruction

The thing is the `cache-misses` event is certainly not very informative here. Indeed, it [references the last-level cache (L3) misses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009988/definition-of-linux-perf-cache-misses-event). Thus, it does not give any information about the L1/L2 misses (previous events do).

> how should I proceed to optimize this?

If the code is latency bound, the solution is to first break any dependency chain in this loop. Unrolling the loop dans rewriting it so to make it more SIMD-friendly can help a lot to improve performance (the reciprocal throughput of this instruction is about 1 cycle as opposed to 12 for the latency so there is a room for improvements in this case).

If the code is memory bound, they you should care about data locality. Data should fit in the L1 cache if possible. There are many tips to do so but it is hard to guide you without more context. This includes for example sorting data, reordering loop iterations, using smaller data types.

There are many possible source of weird unusual unexpected behaviours that can occurs. If such a thing happens, then it is nearly impossible to understand what is going on without the exact code executed. All *details matter* in this case.