# Why might a nostdlib build be slower than using libc?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, x86-64

I don't use strcpy, with AVX2 I implemented strlen, memset, memcpy and memmove so the linker would be happy. I compiled libc and nostdlib the same way except I add `-nostdlib -static` for the nostdlib build. For what reason could the nostdlib version be ~6% slower? I also used `__attribute__` nonnull and `access(write_only, 1)` and such

The only thing I can think of is maybe I messed up the AVX implementation, but my CPU has the same latency and throughput of aligned and unaligned load/store. I'm out of ideas. Profiler shows both look almost the same, just a bit of noise

I'm not sure how I can create a mini reproducible.

Comment: Maybe the stdlib people did a better job than you at strlen, memset, memcpy,memmove?

Comment: What program did you benchmark?  One that makes much use of those functions?

Comment: And are you sure that the stdlib version doesn't get the calls inlined while yours don't?

Comment: If you making an OS, take a look into gnu libc implementation, and copy-pasta.

Comment: @Jeffrey thats why I opened like the way I did. WHY COULD it do better? I already know unaligned and aligned are the same cycles on my machine. I used simd256, no 512 on my machine. HOW COULD it be better? Maybe I should look at most call sites to see if they're inlined in the libc version. It'd make no sense to inline one but not the other

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: That's a good idea I just assume it wouldn't do that differently

Comment: @PeterCordes I noticed something with perf stat. The libc version has MORE of everything, more stalled frontend/backend, branches, branch misses, more task clock time, more user time... It's only less in "seconds time elapsed". A difference I didn't mention is I use futex+atomics (about 5 times per thread, there's no loop) in my nostdlib code while libc uses pthreads. This is bothering me more now that I see the multithread code takes even more time in the libc code

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: `-nostdlib -static` doesn't imply `-fno-builtin-memcpy` or `-fno-builtin` in general. So if that's the only difference in build options, GCC should still be inlining and optimizing away small fixed-size memcpy, doing constant-propagation of `strlen` on string literals, and stuff like that.  If they were still linking any libraries, `-static` would I think disable run-time dispatch according to CPU features for any functions the OP *didn't* define, like `__atomic_load_16` or `memchr` (to pick an AVX2 or AVX-512 w. 256-bit vectors implementation instead of SSE2)

Comment: @Henry: Sounds like the standard build is spending more CPU time across more cores, but costing less wall-clock time.  Without any info on what your program is doing, perhaps you're serializing more of the work somehow.  You don't say what you're using pthreads for vs. lock-free atomics.  This is very much not a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm half profiler noob. I figured out T switches to samples. Now I see in the multicore code both are similar count, but when I launch a child process libc dominates and I get many misses. Page fauls != misses. No std has less faults but writing `-e cache-misses` shows me I get 20% more cache misses. I guess robthebloke answer is correct

Comment: 20% more I-cache misses, like `perf stat -e L1-icache-load-misses`?  (Or on Intel, fewer `idq.dsb_uops` (counts uops that came from the uop cache) or `idq_uops_not_delivered.core` to count cycles where the front-end was stalled, which can also come from iTLB misses.)  Are there any libraries you *are* still linking, after `-nostdlib` gets it to omit libc and libgcc?  You're also omitting pthreads and writing your own `clone()` wrapper to start threads?

Comment: @PeterCordes Simply 'cache-misses'. Using the following all the numbers are close except for 'cache-misses'. `perf stat -e cache-misses,branch-misses,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-icache-load-misses,branch-load-misses,dTLB-load-misses,iTLB-load-misses`

Comment: @PeterCordes everything reports as <100K difference, except cache-misses which is > 1.2M difference

Comment: Then it's unlikely to be robthebloke's answer, unless maybe L1i prefetch is evicting data from outer levels.  `cache-misses` counts L3 cache misses: [definition of linux perf cache-misses event?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60009988)

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh? That's handy to know. TBH my app doesn't try to reuse memory (so I can search old data). It's my app acting poorly with memory. I think it uses something like 1GB per 50MB of input data. It doesn't surprise me I'm getting the occasional L3 problem. Although there's no code running to search the already processed data, it's probably burning write bandwidth moving it to memory and some of my cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the assumption that your memcpy implementation is *perfect*, depending on your platform, it's very unlikely that it will outperform memcpy.

We once had an optimised memcpy function within our console build, and it would happily outperform the std version *(given that we had control over the memory, we could ensure that all allocations were aligned to cache line boundaries, and we never had to worry about any remaining unaligned bytes)*. When we ported the code to PC however, memcpy would always outperform our own implementation *(even though it was doing more work)*.

I tried using the exact same source code as the stdlib version, with all compile flags set to max, and it was still slower than the std version *(I even got so far as to generate a version that had identical machine code - same deal - memcpy was faster)*.

After investigating literally every avenue, it turned out that it was the L1 instruction cache causing the difference. On console, we effectively had one process running - our game. On PC however, due to the frequency with which memcpy was being called in every device driver and app running on the machine, memcpy was almost always resident in the L1 instruction cache, on pretty much every core.

Our version of memcpy wasn't being called frequently enough within our game to ensure it lived in the L1 cache, and that was the difference.

Knowing that, we did manage to construct some artificial benchmarks where we could show that our implementation could match the performance of memcpy *(memory bandwidth limitations meant any performance advantage of our implementation was negligible)*, however in the larger context of our game, calling memcpy was always the best option...

Comment: Thank you that's a fantastic response. I'll try using perf to look at the L1 cache. Since memcpy/move/compare have two buffers, I just assumed there's no way to handle both being unaligned if they were unaligned by different amounts. Since unaligned are same cycles I didn't care. My new question is, did you notice any penalties crossing a boundary VS doing an extra read? As in if my buffer starts at +10 would it be better if I read 54bytes then do 32*2 after that? I think I'll check it for myself since my machine is different than a console but your results if you tried it would be interesting

Comment: After profiling more, it was cache misses. You were correct. If I had to guess why it's because I launch a child process which uses libc

Comment: As a cross check if it's really L1IC misses the simple test would be to write a test benchmark program measuring libc memcpy and build two versions: One linked *statically* against libc, and one linked *dynamically* (shared object) against the very same libc. The statically linked variant should be prone to the same L1IC evictions as OP's homebrew copy implementation.

Comment: @datenwolf: Good idea.  But note that for overall performance, statically linking glibc will I think disable CPU-detection so you'll get the baseline version of memcpy.  Not `__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms` or whatever on CPUs where that's good.  Glibc uses a dynamic linker resolver function to figure out which implementation to use for memcpy / strlen / etc. according to CPU features, since dynamic linking already involves a function pointer so there's no overhead after the resolving happens once.

Comment: @PeterCordes hmm… I'd have expected for also the static variant of glibc to perform dynamic CPU detection. If not, that might be something to add, by patching the first instruction of a generic memcpy with a `jmp` to the CPU optimized variant. Put all the variants next to each other and you can make this a near jump.

Comment: @datenwolf: You mean a `jmp rel8` short jump?  All the implementation are in the same static library which is much less than 2GiB in size, so a `jmp rel32` near jump can easily reach.  Glibc is almost always used in dynamically-linked form, and usually programs don't get a lot faster from having a faster memcpy or strlen, and each statically linked program would have to carry around all the versions of each function in their binary, instead of once system-wide.  Also, a new toally different resolver mechanism would have to get implemented just for static linking.

Comment: @datenwolf: Hmm, I just tried it with `gcc -static -fno-pie -no-pie -g` and single-stepping into a `memcpy`.  It does end up in `__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms` on my Skylake, so apparently I'm wrong.  (It calls to an indirect `jmp`, so you were mostly right.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, yeah I was thinking about `jmp rel8`. W.r.t. faster `memcpy` my personal experience on x86_64 (ca. Haswell) taught me, that copy length matters: Beyond a certain length the speed differences between the various implementations almost vanish and a plain `rep mov` is just about as fast as aligned, vectorized copies via AVX. – We were dealing with a high speed DAQ with an abysmally terrible DMA engine that would operate only within a 2MiB window and we had to race the write pointer at about 6GiB/s. We went through dozens of different copy implementations…

Comment: @datenwolf: Yeah, sounds about right.  With enough load-buffer entries, 16-byte vectors are fine to keep the max number of cache-lines in flight in the memory pipeline for large copies that miss in L3 cache.  Or yeah, `rep movsb` is good for large aligned copies especially if the alternative is SSE2 on a machine that supports AVX.  `strcpy` and `strchr` benefit more from AVX2 for medium-length strings, but glibc's unrolled SSE2 implementation should keep up with memory, at the cost of more uops so more competition for the other hyperthread.

Comment: @datenwolf that's a great idea. I tried it just now and static gets more misses than nostdlib but still somehow faster. I added a flag so I can skip the part that spawns a child process. Using the flag nostdlib is always faster. This problem hurts my head. 6% is < 1second, I should forget about this. It's not a big deal

Comment: @PeterCordes I finally noticed this thread. Do you like problems that hurts people heads? Because my answer to datenwolf hurts my head

Comment: @Henry: I don't like problems without enough info to solve them.  But it's possible to explain how that's plausible: modern CPUs have non-blocking caches (hit-under-miss and miss-under-miss) and can keep track of multiple cache misses in flight at once (memory level parallelism).  So more cache misses doesn't *automatically* mean slower.  A cache miss doesn't fully stall everything until the reorder buffer (ROB) gets full.  Also, with multiple threads, more total CPU time across more cores can incur more cache misses while still having more time not stalled.

Comment: @Henry: Basically, if you're not going to show a [mcve] of your program or enough info to understand the differences in how it runs in the builds you're comparing, the perf numbers alone aren't sufficient info to say much of anything.

Comment: @PeterCordes that's logical. I would love to make a minimal reproducible example but the source isn't open, has >200K lines and it happens at the end. I'm not confident that I could guess how to recreate it and even if I did I wouldn't be confident that it's accurate enough that the solution would apply. I wouldn't save more than 1second so I'll let this problem go